# How can FirebaseMessagingService class can trigger subclass's overrided function?

Tags: java, android, oop, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an SDK and want to develop a logic like Firebase messaging service. For example, if I add the `MyMessageingService` class which extends `FirebaseMessagingService`, inside the `<service>` tags (in this case `FirebaseMessagingService` is a super class and `MyMessagingService` is a sub class) here my question arises.

***My question is how does firebasemessaging service trigger `onNewToken` function in subclass?***

As a result, what I want to do is to trigger a function of subclass in the application side when people who will use the SDK I developed added my service class to the `AndroidManifest.xml` folder of their application, just like in `FirebaseMessagingService`.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first big hurdle you will have to deal with is how you are going to get your service installed and constantly running on a device (FCM has elevated permissions that a normal application will not have thanks to Google Play Services)

If you somehow manage to get around that then you can take a look at the [source](https://github.com/erdalceylan/com-google-firebase-messaging/blob/master/com-google-firebase-messaging/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService.java) of `FirebaseMessagingService` and you will see that Intents get sent to the service and based on that action the service then calls the methods you see in the FCM API (onMessageReceived etc.)